# Reactive transformation of sequence with state variable and zero-or-more projection

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have an observable sequence of overlapping integer ranges, specified as tuples of the form `(begin, end + 1)`, such that both starts and ends of the ranges are non-decreasing in the order of observation. I am transforming them to a sequence of non-overlapping contiguous ranges entirely containing within the union of observed input ranges, witch certain limitations on the output range size. An emission should occur as soon as it is possible to produce a range satisfying the conditions. Assume without loss of generality that the resulting ranges must all be equal in size to a given number. For example, the sequence of ranges `In` is transformed to `Out` as on the diagram below, given the required target range size of 8:

```
     (0,10)   (0,15)   (5,25)
In --O--------O--------O-----------------X
Out--O-----------------OO----------------X
     (0,8)             (8,16)
                        (16,24)
```

The first item `(0,10)` produces one emission `(0,8)`, the second none, since the union of observed-so-far ranges (0,15) does not fit the next contiguous range of length 8, which would be (8,16); and the third input `(5,25)` produces two emissions, as the now observed union of ranges (0,25) will fit 2 additional ranges of size 8, namely `(8,16)` and `(16,24)`.

My question is about the idiomatic expression for this pattern in RX, if one exists. The crucial points are (1) there exists a state variable, the end of the last produced range in my case, and (2) observations are projected to zero, one or more output emissions. My attempt at a solution is not quite pretty and readable:

```
struct Range { public int Beg, End; };

void Main() {
  var source = Observable
    .Range(0, 11)
    .Select(n => new Range { Beg = Math.Max(5 * n - 10, 0), 
                             End = 5 * n + 10 })
    .Dump("source");

  const int chop = 12;

  source
    .Scan((Tuple<int, IObservable<Range>>)null, (acc, range) => {
      var ranges = new List<Range>();
      int s = acc?.Item1 ?? range.Beg;
      for (; s + chop <= range.End; s += chop) {
        ranges.Add(new Range() { Beg = s, End = s + chop });
      }
      return Tuple.Create(s, ranges.ToObservable());
    })
    .Select(t => t.Item2)
    .Concat()
    .Dump("result");
}
```

LINQPad output

```
source
IObservable<Range> 
BegΞΞ EndΞΞ
0 10 
0 15 
0 20 
5 25 
10 30 
15 35 
20 40 
25 45 
30 50 
35 55 
40 60 

result
IObservable<Range> 
BegΞΞ EndΞΞ
0 12 
12 24 
24 36 
36 48 
48 60
```

**ADDED**: Come think of it, I came up with the following solution with explicit mutable state, which reads much better by me:

```
  Observable.Create<Range>(ob => {
    int s = -1;  // Assuming all integers are positive.
    return source.Subscribe(
      rg => {
        if (s < 0) s = rg.Beg;
        for (; s + chop <= rg.End; s += chop)
          ob.OnNext(new Range() { Beg = s, End = s + chop });
      },
      ex => ob.OnError(ex),
      () => ob.OnCompleted()
    );
  }).Dump("result");
```

Is this one idiomatic?

Comment: Your source diagram isn't clear to me. How does `(0, 10)  (0, 15)  (5, 25)` relate to the `O`'s on the marble diagram. It looks like there is an `O` at 2, 11, and 20 (0-based). And how that relates to the output of 2, and 20 I don't see.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I think I improved it as good as I could. Every `O` is labeled by a tuple it represents, with the opening parenthesis in the same screen column as the marble it labels; `In` is labeled above and `Out` below their respective lines.

Comment: @Enigmativity: In fact, I also expended the writing, explaining more of it under the diagram. Hope I made it clearer, and thanks for your feedback.

Comment: It doesn't help. Please re-read my comment.

Comment: @Enigmativity - If I understand what he is saying I do not believe when the `O`'s occur has any bearing on the problem.  I think the the value of the tuple being emitted is the only thing that matters.

Comment: @JasonBoyd - Then I'm even more confused.

Comment: @JasonBoyd: Correct, event "absolute" times are not important. I have never even *seen* a marble diagram where time would matter, or would be defined whatsoever, as it is rather impossible to time events in a generally non-realtime system; in my understanding, only the order is. To be specific, I think my notion of a marble diagram is same as that used on http://reactivex.io. Apparently, not everybody was taught by the same textbooks :)